# tikz syntax name dot number

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I found a code example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/inertial-navigation-system/

where I see that positioning:

```
\node (naveq) [naveqs] {Navigation equations};
\path (naveq.140)+(-\blockdist,0) node (gyros) [sensor] {Gyros};
```

What is the meaning of the "name.value" syntax mean? I see it positions to the left side. If I change to:

```
 \path (naveq.1cm)+(-\blockdist,0) node (gyros) [sensor] {Gyros};
```

it positions to the top.

Can both be done simultaneously and can measurement units also used for horizontal positions?

Comment: The value is an angle, 0 degrees is the right side, 90 degrees the top, etc. Not sure what happens when you use `1cm` there.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thanks!... after removing the `(-\blockdist,0)` I see the effect my self :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a coordinate like `(<nodename>.<value>)`, the `<value>` indicates an anchor of the node. It can either be a compass direction (`north`, `north east`, `east` etc.) or a number, corresponding to an angle in degrees. That is, `foo.0` is the same as `foo.east`, i.e. the right side of the node named `foo`, and  `foo.90` is the same as `foo.north`, i.e. the top of `foo`.

Hence,

```
\path (naveq.140)+(-\blockdist,0) node ...
```

means start at the point that is about north west on the `naveq` node, then move `\blockdist` to the left, and place the node here.

However, when you do `naveq.1cm`, the `1cm` is converted to `pt` (the basic unit for TikZ), and the point value is used for the angle. As 1cm is about 28.45pt, `naveq.1cm` is the same as `naveq.28.45`, as illustrated by this example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle,minimum size=3cm,draw,name=a]  {};
\fill [red] (a.1cm) circle[radius=5pt];
\fill [blue] (a.28.45) circle[radius=3pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

As you can see both the red and blue dots are placed at the same place.